# Firebase JS SDK - SMS verification code timeout

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

is there a way to set a duration of when the SMS verification code will expire in Firebase JS SDK?

The following function doesn't seem to accept timeout parameter in firebase@7.18.0

```
firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptcha);
```

However it appears that Android SDK does accept timeout as secondary parameter for verifying phone number.

Android SDK url :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider#verifyPhoneNumber(java.lang.String,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20android.app.Activity,%20com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I saw in the documentation, there is not timeout in Firebase Auth SDK for JS.

 The SDK you have mentioned in the question is for Android - Java. 
 In Java, we have `onCodeAutoRetrieval` (i.e) Auto Code Retrieval of OTP SMS, so we might have a timeout.